# Keep the footer the below or at the bottom of the wrapper / content

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, footer

**My Footer appears at the bottom of my content until I scroll down and then back up, then it appears half way up my page in the middle of my content.**

I'v made several webpages I find it interesting I have just run into this problem, I have used similar code to other projects.

Heres Is my HTML and the CSS.

```
 <body> 
 <div id="wrapper">
 <header>
    <nav>
    </nav>
 </header>
    <div id="content">
    </div> 
 </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
 </body>
```

CSS:

```
#body {
width: 100%; 
background-color: #ebebeb;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;}

#nav{
margin:0;
padding:0px;
text-align:center;
width: 100%;
height: 44px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 15;
clear: both;}

#wrapper {
width: 100%; 
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
z-index: 10;
clear: both;
overflow: auto;}

#content-form {
width: 50%;
height: auto;
background-color: white;
    margin-top: 100px;
margin-left: 25%;
margin-right: 25%;
margin-bottom: 0;   
padding: 1em;
padding-bottom:0;
text-align: center;}

#footer {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
clear: both;
background-color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
padding: auto;
z-index: 5;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your body's `position` to `relative`. [Here's a codepen](http://codepen.io/erquhart/pen/vqjxs). I'm guessing you didn't cut and paste this from your live code, as your css contains things like `#body`. I fixed that stuff in the pen.

Comment: Thanks for your respond, the hashtag before body is not in my live code. Even in codepen the footer does not stay below the wrapper, and overlaps.

Comment: No, the footer is at the bottom. I added a 4px black outline to the footer for clarity, check again.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the body and html tags a min-height of 100%. If content doesn't fill the entire viewport, an absolute position set to bottom: 0 won't actually be at the bottom.